Why is encryption data at rest and encryption in transit data must be disabled when migrating the ec2 cache to AWS Elasticache?
I had launched the ec2 instance where i have installed redis, and added some data in it. and then after that i wanted to migrate that cache from ec2 redis to aws elasticcache cluster, so for that i created the cluster in aws and started migration, but first time i enabled the encryption in data at rest and encryption in transit data, so it was showing that the migration cannot be happen. But when i created another cluster by disabling the in transit and data at rest encryption, it got migrated. So i wanted to know why is this? and How to migrate the data by encrypting?
First time i enabled the encryption in data at rest and encryption in transit data, so it was showing that the migration cannot be happen. But when i created another cluster by disabling the in transit and data at rest encryption, it got migrated. So i wanted to know why is this? and How to migrate the data by encrypting?

it's not supported for the migration :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Migration-Prepare.html

It doesn't have either encryption in-transit or encryption at-rest enabled.

I'm not sure why is this a requirement, but it let me guess about performance concerns while migration.
